# zsh trap permission denied with function

Tags: shell, zsh

in zsh - I make heavy use of command_not_found_handler - to allow various tools I have defined to run at the shell level - mainly to jump me around the place.

but I'd really like to know if there's a similar way to trap "permission denied".  What I'm actually trying to achieve is to be able to change into a directory without typing *cd* - so I was thinking I could drop something like this into .zshrc:

```bash
permission_denied_handler() {
    if [ -d $1 ]; then   
        echo changing to $1
        cd $1
        return 0
    else  
        echo permission denied
        return 127
    fi
}
```

but of course that doesn't work.  Is there a way to achieve what I want?   The reason I want it is because I have the command not found handler - so for instance if I want to jump to say my downloads directory from anywhere on my machine, I just say "downloads" - but if I'm in ~ - instead of triggering command not found, it sees the directory and just says permission denied :(

and the reason I use command_not_found instead of just something that builds aliases is that I'm constantly adding new commands - so if I have 8 shell windows open, in this way, as soon as I add a new command, it's active in all windows - but if I added them to .zshrc or something, I'd have to refresh or restart the shells.

Comment: In bash, you could do this (albeit intercepting the command before it runs instead of fixing it up after it tries and fails) with a DEBUG trap. No idea if zsh has an equivalent, or what it would be.

Comment: On a related note: If you wouldn't accept a bash-only answer that doesn't work at all on zsh, you shouldn't have the bash tag on your question.

Comment: I was thinking that there are more bash people out there - and a bash answer might work... and.... excitingly - it looks like debug trap _does_ work under .zsh. - so playing with it now - it may lead me to what I want - thanks!!!

Comment: YAY - trap didn't actually do what I wanted - but finding the doco for it got me to where I wanted - the magic is "preexec".      ty!   https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html

Comment: actually - preexec works, but it doesn't.   I can change trap and change directory successfully - but I can't modify the command - so it still says permission denied.  Better than what I had - but ugly

Comment: Hmm. With a debug trap in bash, the exit status of the trap determines whether the original command is executed, so you can do something intended to replace the command, and then return a nonzero status to cause that original command not to be executed.

Comment: How does what you're trying to do differ from `setopt auto_cd` and possibly `CDPATH`?

Comment: it doesn't - setopt auto_cd is exactly what I wanted...  I didn't know about it - thank you!

Comment: so setopt auto_cd is my real solution - but the trap is close - I can't find any documentation on it about getting at the command - in bash it seems to be $bash_command - but I can't see what it is in zsh.  But anyway - I'm happy with auto_cd